# How can this function transform give me a dataframe with the data from an input file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing Python scripts for a database. I've written this code to return a Pandas DataFrame with duplicate rows removed:

```
from transformer import BaseTransformer
import pandas as pd

class MyTransformer(BaseTransformer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self,df):

        for index, row in df.iterrows(): # pandas.DataFrame.iterrows iterates over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs

            df = pd.DataFrame(df.drop_duplicates()) 
            # df is an Object, it is the name of my Pandas dataframe
            # pd.DataFrame is a data object constructor
            # drop_duplicates() is the method name

            df=df.drop_duplicates()
                
        return pd.DataFrame(df)
```

There's a file with the input test cases that I'm using in a test environment. I don't think I have to read the input file, but I'm confused as to how this function transform `distinct().py` will give me a new dataframe "df" with all the data in the file. If I run it as it is above I don't get any errors but the result file for the test cases returns the same dataframe that was input without removing any duplicate rows.

Comment: How does the input variable 'df' in def transform(self, df) input a test file with test cases?

Comment: why are you dropping duplicates , inside for loop ?????

Comment: @qaiser I'm iterating through the dataframe looking for duplicate rows to drop. how else could I do it?

Comment: without iterating ,df.drop_duplicates()  works